# SOLID principles. How to not get everything jammed at the higher level class?

Tags: java, solid-principles

I just completed a java application using mostly Utility classes, then I read about SOLID principles over the weekend so I'm refactoring the whole application to follow that principle. There's one problem that I encountered while trying it out, therefore, I must be doing it wrong so can anyone lead me to the right path?
Example:

```
public interface ID { }

public class D implements ID {
  //this class has a lot of dependencies that I do not want in class B but at some point
 // I have to create it. When is that point?
}

public interface IC { }

public class C implements IC {
  //this class has a lot of dependencies that I do not want in class B
}

public interface IB { }

public class B implements IB {
  public IC c;
  public ID d; 

  // this class depends on the 2 (or more) interfaces IC and ID so 
  // it won't have dependencies on concrete classes. But if the 
  // concrete classes are not used, then they all start bubbling up to the          
  // higher level class (let say class A below), and class A would know about and have 
  // dependencies on way so many objects, doesn't it?
}

public class A {
   ID d = new D();
   IC c = new C();
   IB b = new B(d, c); // b could given to some other classes
}
```

As you can see, the more abstract level and the more objects I have, the worse it gets. what is your technique to reduce this?

My first thought is having a client for the interfaces in the middle that knows everything about the concrete classes of those interfaces (kind of like a factory class), then class A would use that client class, but problem still remain. Class A depends on Client class that depends on other concrete classes. I'm just making a longer chain instead of many short chains.

Comment: All application needs a [**composition root**](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).

Comment: It states "as close as possible to the entry point". Is it normal for applications' entry point (or near entry point) to have multiple huge objects (space wise) that consisted of multiple smaller objects recursively?

Comment: Yes it is, but you may also want to read [this blog post](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/04/Composeobjectgraphswithconfidence/).

Comment: Yeah, I've read that but some commenters made very good argument such as loading a huge object at start up and make it available throughout the application instead of giving scope to each object when needed since most application only required part of the object at any particular time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This design looks good to me. There is no need to create further abstraction layers above class A, since that way - as you correctly realised - it would never end. The system must have an edge, abstractions should be resolved in some place. Doing it in class A is fine, as long as this class is only responsible for wiring together the other objects (so you may call class A "Configuration").

So as long as you want to work only with plain java without any frameworks, you are good to go with this design. Using Spring (or any other dependency injection library) for DI may be a plus, but introduce it only if you feel it needed. By the way doing dependency injection with spring's JavaConfig would result in almost the same code as your current class A, with some annotations.

Comment: The key here is that class `A` is **only** responsible for wiring and does nothing else, thus satisfying the Single Responsibility Principle.

Comment: Out of curiosity, without a DI library how would class `B` access the objects in class `A`, i.e. how would the beans be injected?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. The `IB b = new B(d, c);` line is a proper constructor injection without any DI library, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, sorry. What I meant to say was, how would the object `b` constructed by `A` be accessed by a client class, i.e. how would `A` go about injecting its beans without the use of a DI library? Presumably some business logic requires the object `b`. How would that connection be made, from business logic to `A`?

Comment: To ask the question another way, what does `A` do with its beans after wiring them together? How are the beans made accessible to the application without a DI library?

Comment: @jaco0646 Class `A` is the application bootstrap code. For instance `class Bootstrap { x = new X(); y = new Y(); app = new App(x, y); app.start(); }` Everything is already wired together so there's no need for further injection...

Comment: From Robert Martin's video, he said something about the possibility "shipping the modules separately", and I still cannot see how this is done. Any module X that uses class A will automatically have a dependency on B, C, D concrete classes. Should A implement an interface and let module X depends on that interface and start another chain?

Comment: "Any module X that uses class A"
As said above, class A is the place for the configuration (and maybe also the entry point where the application gets initialized). As part of this, there is no class X that depends on A. That is what I originally meant by "A is the edge of the system".

Comment: I've created a snippet as an example, hopefully good enough to clean up misunderstandings: http://pastebin.com/QxaBRAgZ
edit: yet another note: in the Main and Configuration classes we use concrete implementations because by "the edge of the system" we also mean that these classes are not under the subject of reusability or flexibility. Once again, the Configuration object has the same responsibility as a spring xml file has. The only difference is that Configuration is implemented in Java and not in XML.

Comment: Oh ok, I misunderstood your answer. I assume I'm heading the wrong path since the top level class (Class A) is going to be jammed with every kinds of objects and was wondering what others do about that. From your comment and the commenter above, it seems to be ok for the highest layer to be jammed with objects and it's best to have a composition root (edge) close to main entry point as possible. Thanks.